# priv-app provide jar for other apps

Tags: android, android-build

Is it possible that an app located in *system/priv-app/* provides executable code to other apps?

I want to achieve something **similar to the android system components**:
When you develop an app you only need to reference the components from the system (like the Activity class) without actually including them into the app. But when you run your app, the system somehow figures out that you need this class and gives you access.

How exactly does this android internal process work and can it be adopted?

Comment: "the system somehow figures out that you need this class and gives you access" -- not really. The Android framework JAR (with the real implementations of the classes, not the one packaged in the SDK) is included in the zygote.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well then, can I provide another jar to be included?

Comment: Build a custom ROM, and you definitely can, as [I have seen device manufacturers add extra crap to the zygote](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/12/11/manufacturers-keep-your-hands-off-my-zygote.html). I don't know the mechanics of that. And I would be very surprised if an app -- even one in `/system/priv-app` -- can recompile the zygote on the fly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the link. This was really helpful